# haskell StateTの使い方を知りたい(乱数の最大値を保存するコードを書きたい)

Tags: haskell

HaskellのStateTの使い方を理解するため、
乱数の上限値を保存するコードを書こうとしているのですが、いまいち分りません。以下現在のコードです

```
import System.Random
import Control.Monad.State

getRandom :: Int -> IO Int
getRandom x = getStdRandom $ randomR (0,x)

getCurrent :: StateT Int IO Int
getCurrent = do
  i <- get
  x <- lift $ getRandom i
  return x

updateMax :: x -> StateT Int IO ()
updateMax x = do
  put x

main = do
  a <- flip evalState 0 $ do
    updateMax 1000
    getCurrent
  print a
```

どうなれば上限値を更新・保存するように出来るでしょうか？

命令型ならこんな感じのコードになると思います。

```
Max = 0;
func getRandom = RandRange(0,Max);


func main = {
  Max=100;
  print(getRandom()); // 出力 50 等
  Max=1000;
  print(getRandom()); // 出力 500 等
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 「Couldn't match type ‘x’ with ‘Int’」というエラーメッセージの通り、`put`によって`StateT Int`の`Int`という具体的な方の値を更新しようとしているにもかかわらず、`x`を指定してしまっています。
2. 「Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘Data.Functor.Identity.Identity’」というエラーメッセージのとおり、`evalStateT`を使うべきところで`evalState`を使ってしまっています。（`type State s = StateT s Identity`という定義なのを覚えておいてください！）

以上を解決すれば、意図通りに動作するはずです。

---

以下は古い回答です。いただいたコメントとの整合性をとるために一応残しておきます。

`updateMax` のところで「`x`が現在保存している値（`get`で取得できる値）より大きければ更新する」というロジックを加えるのがポイントです。
難しければ、ほかのプログラミング言語で命令型のアルゴリズムで試しに書いてみると分かりやすいかも知れません。  
`StateT` はそうした命令型のアルゴリズムを翻訳するのにも使えるので。

Comment: すみません、最大値という書き方がまずかったかもしれませんが、上限値という意味です。入力された上限値を状態として保存しておき、0からその上限値までの乱数を生成して返すような仕組みです。命令型でやる場合は単に上限値をグローバル変数で保存して書き換えるだけだと思います

Comment: 命令型の場合のコードを追記しました

Comment: すみません、寝ぼけてました... アルゴリズムがわからないのではなくMonad Transformerを使った場合に型を合わせられなかった、ということですね... 少々お待ちを。

Comment: 編集されていたのを見落としていました。ありがとうございます。そのとおりでした。

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました。
https://wiki.haskell.org/Simple_StateT_use
を参照しました

```
import System.Random
import Control.Monad.State

type MaxState a = StateT Int IO a

getRandom :: Int -> IO Int
getRandom x = getStdRandom $ randomR (0,x)

getCurrent :: MaxState Int
getCurrent = do
  i <- get
  x <- lift $ getRandom i
  return x

updateMax :: Int -> MaxState ()
updateMax x = do
  a <- get
  put x

process :: MaxState Int
process = do
  updateMax 10
  a <- getCurrent
  liftIO $ print a
  updateMax 10000
  b <- getCurrent
  liftIO $ print b
  return b

main :: IO ()
main = do
  x <- runStateT process 1
  print x
```